# Console menu to print dynamic parameters in Python script

Tags: python, parameters, console-application

So, I have a code of calculation of radiation doses. I have some parameters that depends on choose of DTU(1,2,3) and these ones are getting from json files. There is a code on Python:

```py
import json
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
import keyboard
import time


init()

with open("DTU.json", 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print('Расчет дозы для трех установов ДТУ')
print("Чтобы, изменить параметры, введите букву н и два раза нажмите Enter")
a1_values = [float(data[dtu]['a1']) for dtu in data]
b1_values = [float(data[dtu]['b1']) for dtu in data]
a2_values = [float(data[dtu]['a2']) for dtu in data]
a3_values = [float(data[dtu]['a3']) for dtu in data]
b2_values = [float(data[dtu]['b2']) for dtu in data]
b3_values = [float(data[dtu]['b3']) for dtu in data]
k_sens1 = [1.5, 1.2245, 1, 0.8163, 0.6666, 0.5442, 0.4444]
k_sens2 = [1.4964, 1.2239, 1, 0.8167, 0.6678, 0.5459, 0.4461]
k_sens3 = [1.4948, 1.2236, 1, 0.8169, 0.6682, 0.54665, 0.4471]



while True:
    # DTU-1(start)
    dtu = int(input("Номер ДТУ = "))

    if dtu == 1:
        a_m = [float(a1_values[0]), float(a2_values[0]), float(a3_values[0])]
        b_m = [float(b1_values[0]), float(b2_values[0]), float(b3_values[0])]
        b = b_m[0]
        a = a_m[0]
        k = k_sens1
        print("a1= ", a_m[0], "a2 = ", a_m[1], "a3= ",  a_m[2])
        print("b1= ", b_m[0], "b2 = ", a_m[1], "b3= ",  a_m[2])
        elif dtu == 2:
            a_m = [float(a1_values[1]), float(a2_values[1]), float(a3_values[1])]
            a = a_m[0]
            b_m = [float(b1_values[1]), float(b2_values[1]), float(b3_values[1])]
            b = b_m[0]
            k = k_sens2
    else:
        a_m = [float(a1_values[2]), float(a2_values[2]), float(a3_values[2])]
        a = a_m[0]
        b_m = [float(b1_values[2]), float(b2_values[2]), float(b3_values[2])]
        b = b_m[0]
        k = k_sens3
    # DTU-1(end)


    # KdrDf(start)
    n = input("K_group = ")
    n = int(n)
    ks = k[n+1]  # Correct index for ks
    print(ks)
    k_dr_str = input('K_dreif = ')
    if ',' in k_dr_str:
            k_dr_str = k_dr_str.replace(',', '.')
    k_dr = float(k_dr_str)

    while True:
        i1_str = input("I1 = ")
        i2_str = input("I2 = ")

        if i1_str =="н":
            break

        if ',' in i1_str:
            i1_str = i1_str.replace(',', '.')
        if ',' in i2_str:
            i2_str = i2_str.replace(',', '.')

        i_1 = float(i1_str)
        i_2 = float(i2_str)

        i1 = i_1 * ks
        i2 = i_2 * ks
        d1 = (k_dr * i1 * a) + b
        d2 = (k_dr * i2 * a) + b
        D = ((d1 + d2) / 2) 

        if D <=1.5:
            b = b_m[0]
            a = a_m[0]
            d1 = (k_dr * i1 * a) + b
            d2 = (k_dr * i2 * a) + b
            D = ((d1 + d2) / 2) 
            print(f"{Fore.GREEN}{round(D, 3)}{Style.RESET_ALL}")
        elif 1.5 <= D < 15:
            a = a_m[1]
            b = b_m[1]
            d1 = (k_dr * i1 * a) + b
            d2 = (k_dr * i2 * a) + b
            D = ((d1 + d2) / 2) 
            print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}{round(D, 3)}{Style.RESET_ALL}")
        elif D >= 15:
            a = a_m[2]
            b = b_m[2]
            d1 = (k_dr * i1 * a) + b
            d2 = (k_dr * i2 * a) + b
            D = ((d1 + d2) / 2) 
            print(f"{Fore.RED}{round(D, 3)}{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```

JSON file:

```json
{
    "DTU_011": {
        "a1": 33.714,
        "b1": 0,
        "a2": 33.297,
        "b2": 0.0563,
        "a3": 39.218,
        "b3": -1.2307
    },
    "DTU_012": {
        "a1": 4.1221,
        "b1": 0,
        "a2": 4.6839,
        "b2": -0.125,
        "a3": 4.6839,
        "b3": -0.125
    },
    "DTU_013": {
        "a1": 13.11,
        "b1": 0.0293,
        "a2": 9.3092,
        "b2": 0.3717,
        "a3": 9.2746,
        "b3": -0.1513
    }
}
```

And the situation is - I need my parameters like: ***a_m, b_m, dtu, n and k_dr*** to be displayed as console menu, and it must be positioned at the right corner. I will be good if position of this menu would be static